# WKWebView isn't clickable outside it's contentInset

Tags: ios8, wkwebview

I have an app with a UIWebView and I need to change it into WKWebView.
Everything works perfectly, except when the webView needs to be with contentInset that is not 0.
The problem is, the WKWebView doesn't receive touches outside of the bounds of its scrollView's contentInset.

I've made a simple example app for testing it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   WKWebViewConfiguration *config = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
   self.wkWebView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:config];
   [self.view addSubview:self.wkWebView];

   self.wkWebView.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(200, 0, 0, 0);
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:/www.google.com"];
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [self.wkWebView loadRequest:request];
}
```

When I scroll the webView above it's top inset, I can't click on the webView in that area.

I've tried to look for similar issues, but had no luck, did anyone else encounter this problem?

Thanks

Comment: I found this bug report in webKit - https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=134230 if this is the same issue, it wont be fixed...

Comment: Anybody have an update on this? I'm trying to implement a web view with an overlay that scrolls off with the web view. For various reasons I can't work with the solution provided by smileEvday. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @DanielShteremberg we didn't find a solution yet. We're still using UIWebView...

Answer (score 5):

I encounter the same problem, Before iOS 8, I use UIWebView, everything works fine, But WKWebview can not respond click event when content area display in contentInset area.
I finally solve this problem by Add a empty div in HTML string, at the beginning the body.

```
<div style='width:100%;height:500px'></div>
```

Then the WKWebView can get the same effect like set contentInset, and respond to user tap correctly!

Answer (score 3):

The issue seems to be *finally* solved as of the first betas of Xcode 10 and iOS 12.

Comment: Thanks for updating!, we'll check it out