# Portion of WKWebView that is beyond contentOffset.y = 0 is not clickable

Tags: wkwebview

I want to add a header above the web content of a WKWebView, the web contents will be scrolled over the header as the user scrolls up. So I set the WKWebView's contentInset.top = 200. ( height of the header view).

Everything is fine, excepts that when I scroll up, the web contents that are beyond the ContentOffSet( ContentOffSet.y < 0 ) become not clickable.

I tried the same with tradition WebView, there is no such problem. Anyone has any clue?

Thank You!

Comment: Oh, duplicated. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27755251/wkwebview-isnt-clickable-outside-its-contentinset)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WKWebView isn't clickable outside it's contentInset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27755251/wkwebview-isnt-clickable-outside-its-contentinset)