# How to convert height to WKWebView's coordinate

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I changed WKWebView's contentInset so i can add a headerView.but web can't be clicked within insets.[smileEvday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29361854/7238980) adviced me to add a empty div in HTML string, at the beginning of the body.if contentInset.top is equal to 100,height of the empty div should be 100px when using UIWebView.But I failed to calculate the height of the div when using WKWebView.if contentInset.top is equal to 100, how to calculate the height of the empty div?

Comment: Have you ever try getHieght WKWebView with method  [self performSelector:@selector(getHeight) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];

Comment: Do you want to add a web based header or are you willing to have a native UIView header?

Comment: a native UIView header